# cancan ability through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

I'm using CanCan for defining a users abilities, but I just ran into a snag where I'm trying to only allow the user to manage a model through it's parent.

For example. 
A book has an author, a book has many chapters. 
I want only the author to be able to manage chapters.
My book model has an author_id. 
My chapter model has a book_id.

in my Ability.rb file I have

```
 user.has_role? :author
            can :manage, Book, :author_id => user.id
            can :manage, Chapter
            can :read, :all
        else
```

but I don't see anywhere in the documentation where I define that the author can only manage the chapters of the book. Is there another way to authorize a book and all it's relationships? Or am I supposed to somehow define the chapter as belonging to the book? I am not saving the chapter through the book model (it is not nested).

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```
 user.has_role? :author
            can :manage, Book, :author_id => user.id
            can :manage, Chapter do |chapter|
              chapter.book.author_id == user.id
            end
            can :read, :all
        else
```

Maybe there's a better solution...